# Low accuracy while solving a multi-variable equation numerically

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

My question is as following:

I was trying to make a function `Vs2[r]` with two parameters fit a set of conditions.

`Vs2[r]`:

```
δa[r_] = E^(-r^2/(2 a^2))/((2 π)^(3/2) a^3); α = 1;
Vs2[r_] = 
  - (α/r) Erf[r/(Sqrt[2] a)] + c2 a^2 δa[r] + 
    d1 a^4 Laplacian[δa[r], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"];
a = 1;
```

with two parameters `c2` and `d1`, and `a` was set to `1`.

It must fit the condition:

```
{(Vs2[r] - evShifted[[20]]) ef[[20]] - 1/2 Evaluate[D[ef[[20]], {r, 2}]] == 0,
 (Vs2[r] - evShifted[[15]]) ef[[15]] - 1/2 Evaluate[D[ef[[15]], {r, 2}]] == 0}
```

(`evShifted` and `ef` were coming from here:

```
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r;

Module[{shift = 10, d = 2000, n = 20, ev}, 
  {ev, ef} = 
  NDEigensystem[
     {shift f[r] + V[r] f[r] - 1/2 f''[r], DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0, True]}, 
     f[r], {r, 0, d}, n, 
     Method -> 
       {"SpatialDiscretization" -> 
         {"FiniteElement", 
           {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> ∞}}];
   evShifted = ev - shift]
```

as a heads-up,this part might be costly in time and memory.)

So I choose `r = 1` to evaluate the condition:

```
eqn1 := {((Vs2[r] - evShifted[[20]]) ef[[20]] - 
  1/2 Evaluate[D[ef[[20]], {r, 2}]]) == 
0, ((Vs2[r] - evShifted[[15]]) ef[[15]] - 
  1/2 Evaluate[D[ef[[15]], {r, 2}]]) == 0} /. r -> 1
```

and use `FindRoot` to solve it:

```
FindRoot[eqn1, {{c2, -50., -30}, {d1, -10, -5}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "Secant", PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

When I put my result back into the left side of the equations,what I hoped was numbers very close to `0`,but what I had was this:entering

```
{(Vs2[r] - evShifted[[20]]) ef[[20]] - 
  1/2 Evaluate[
  D[ef[[20]], {r, 2}]], (Vs2[r] - evShifted[[19]]) ef[[19]] - 
  1/2 Evaluate[D[ef[[19]], {r, 2}]]} /. r -> 1 /. %
```

and got

```
{-0.0000363407, -0.0000453644}
```

I tried different methods and options to get things right but failed.Other function like `NSolve` and `Reduce` just don't have a solution.So why's that?Is there any way to increase the accuracy or other approaches to find a valid combination of `c2` and `d1`?I'd really appreciate it if anyone helps.

I tried mannually search for the values of `c2` and `d1`,here's my code:

```
c2d1 = {c2 -> -53.1356, d1 -> -6.0104};
sol = With[{r1 = 10^-10, r2 = 2000}, 
        ParametricNDSolve[{(Vs2[r] /. c2d1) f[r] - 1/2 f''[r] == e f[r], 
            f[r2] == 0, f'[r2] == -r1}, f, {r, r2, r1}, e]];
FindRoot[f[e][10^-10] == 0 /. sol, {e, -0.0012, -0.0013}]
((e /. %) - evShifted[[20]])/evShifted[[20]]
FindRoot[f[e][10^-9] == 0 /. sol, {e, -0.0023, -0.0024}]
((e /. %) - evShifted[[15]])/evShifted[[15]]
```

It's totally mannual,I input some values into the first line and see how's the result,starting value's coming from previous calculation.This way I'm able to keep the error lower than `10^-6`.(And that's my goal.The way I did bfore was just a shortcut,I thought once it fits the differential equation,the corresponding `e` would be very close.)

Comment: I believe that by using machine arithmetic to define `V[r_]`, you force all later calculation to done with machine arithmetic. Which means that asking for more precision in `FindRoot` doesn't actually get you any more accuracy. The old numerics principle applies: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: `δa[r]` is not defined in the question, so your results cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry I forgot to define `\[delta]a[r]`.I have added it right before the definition of `Vs2[r]`.

Comment: Can you provide an analytical proof that the final residuals should be zero?  Doing so would provide a framework for searching for the lost precision, which could be due to the finite accuracy of `v`, the size of `d`, the accuracy of the `FindRoot` results, the accuracy of `NDEigensystem`, or perhaps other issues.  Also, is there any way to increase the speed of the calculation?

Comment: It's an approximation method,so I'm not sure if the final residuals should be zero.But I'm not asking for zero anyway.When I simplified the equations,what I got is a linear system and analytically there should be only one possible solution but from some similar work there can be many sets of results.So I wonder if it only asks for a tolerance,not some absolute solution?I'm new in this numerically soving things,so if I got it wrong anywhere,feel free to point it out.Thank you.